# Can't find telemetryclient in microsoft application insights nuget

Tags: c#, .net-4.5, azure-application-insights, nuget-package

I am working on an old application in .NET 4.5.2.  I need to upgrade the app insights nuget package from Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.18.0-beta3 to 2.21.0.  The code currently (2.18.0-beta3) has TelemetryClient which was referenced with `using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;` but after the upgrade, the TelemetryClient is no longer in that namespace, nor is it in any other namespace in that nuget package.  Where can I get access to the app insights TelemetryClient?

This is what I see:
[image]

The build error is:

`The type or namespace name 'TelemetryClient' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights'`

This is what I see in my references:
[image]

Parts of the .csproj that deal with the ApplicationInsights package:

```html
<Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Agent.Intercept.2.4.0\lib\net45\Microsoft.AI.Agent.Intercept.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector, Version=2.21.0.429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.21.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector, Version=2.21.0.429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.2.21.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.AI.PerfCounterCollector.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel, Version=2.21.0.429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.21.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.AI.ServerTelemetryChannel.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.Web, Version=2.21.0.429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.2.21.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.AI.Web.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer, Version=2.21.0.429, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.2.21.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.AI.WindowsServer.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights, Version=2.18.0.265, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
  <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.2.21.0\lib\net452\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
...
<ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="favicon.ico" />
    <Content Include="Global.asax" />
    <Content Include="ApplicationInsights.config">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
...
<Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports" BeforeTargets="PrepareForBuild">
<PropertyGroup>
  <ErrorText>This project references NuGet package(s) that are missing on this computer. Use NuGet Package Restore to download them.  For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=322105. The missing file is {0}.</ErrorText>
</PropertyGroup>
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.Net.Compilers.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.1.0.0\build\Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.props'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.targets'))" />
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.targets')" Text="$([System.String]::Format('$(ErrorText)', '..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.targets'))" />
</Target>
<Import Project="..\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\OctoPack.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\OctoPack.targets')" />
<Target Name="EnsureOctoPackImported" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild" Condition="'$(OctoPackImported)' == ''">
<Error Condition="!Exists('..\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\OctoPack.targets') And ('$(RunOctoPack)' != '' And $(RunOctoPack))" Text="You are trying to build with OctoPack, but the NuGet targets file that OctoPack depends on is not available on this computer. This is probably because the OctoPack package has not been committed to source control, or NuGet Package Restore is not enabled. Please enable NuGet Package Restore to download them. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317567." HelpKeyword="BCLBUILD2001" />
<Error Condition="Exists('..\packages\OctoPack.3.4.2\tools\OctoPack.targets') And ('$(RunOctoPack)' != '' And $(RunOctoPack))" Text="OctoPack cannot be run because NuGet packages were restored prior to the build running, and the targets file was unavailable when the build started. Please build the project again to include these packages in the build. You may also need to make sure that your build server does not delete packages prior to each build. For more information, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=317568." HelpKeyword="BCLBUILD2002" />
</Target>
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DependencyCollector.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.PerfCounterCollector.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.TelemetryChannel.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WindowsServer.targets')" />
<Import Project="..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.targets" Condition="Exists('..\packages\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.2.21.0\build\Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.targets')" />
```

Comment: TelemetryClient should still be a part of Microsoft.ApplicationInsights as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient?view=azure-dotnet

Comment: I have this one installed: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.ApplicationInsights/2.21.0?_src=template

Comment: Try restarting VS, sometimes happens. Make sure 2.21 installed completely.

Comment: I closed all of my VSs and cleared my nuget caches.  It is still not finding the reference.

Comment: Not sure why this was closed.  It is a valid question.  I have uninstalled it, cleaned the solution, cleared nuget caches, installed, rebuilt, still get the error.

Comment: Why was this closed? This isn't asking for recommendations, it's asking `where is that class` ? The answer may easily be `that's a configuration setting now`

Comment: The docs say that [TelemetryClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.applicationinsights.telemetryclient?view=azure-dotnet) still exists. Are you getting a compilation error? This may be a problem with Intellisense, not a missing class. Please post code a minimal example that reproduces the problem along with the full compilation error. You should be able to create a simple Console application with just `new Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient();` to reproduce the error

Comment: Yes, I will update the question with the actual build error message.

Comment: I cannot find an online C# coding tool that support .NET 4.5.2 so that I can recreate and share.

Comment: I attempted to open this in VS2019 to see if that was the issue, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @ScubaSteve -  Could you please share your `.csproj` file.

Answer (score 0):

- In Visual Studio, I have created a `.NET Framework 4.5.2`.
- Tried to Configure `Application Insights` from both VS 2019 and VS 2022 by right clicking on the Project folder.

[image]

- `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` version `2.15.0.44797` is Installed.

[image]

- In `NuGet Package Manager` you can see,`Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` is deprecated from version `2.15.0` to `2.20.0`.

[image]

[image]

- Installed the available `2.21.0` latest version.

[image]

- You can see `TelemetryClient` is available.

***In `ASP.NET` Web Form***

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;

TelemetryClient telemetryClient = new TelemetryClient();
```

[image]

***In `MVC` Application***

```cs
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
 private TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;
 public ActionResult Index(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
            return View();
        }
```

- Make sure you have `ApplicationInsights.config`(auto generated while configuring Application Insights) in the Root Directory of the Project.
  [image]

***Local Output:***

[image]

***Deployed Application Output:***

[image]

Thanks [@cijothomas](https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-dotnet/issues/1972) for confirming the `TelemetryClient` usage.

- As we have upgraded the `Microsoft.ApplicationInsights` to `2.21.0` version. Make sure all the packages related to `Application Insights` are also updated to latest version. Mainly  `Microsoft.AI.DependencyCollector`.

[image]

References taken from MSDoc [1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/tutorial-asp-net-custom-metrics#getting-a-telemetryclient-instance) and [2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net-dependencies#automatically-tracked-dependencies)

Comment: I made sure all 7 Microsoft.ApplicationInights.* nuget packages are v2.21.0 (except Intercept which is 2.4.0).  But, I viewed my references and there's a yellow warning icon beside Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.  It does not give me any info as to why.  I updated my question with a screenshot of it.

Comment: One of the package related to Application Insights might have deprecated version.

Comment: Upgrading the vesion of ApplicationInsights might not update the other appinsights packages.I suggest you to check each one.

Comment: I did, each one is 2.21.0.

Comment: Could you please share your `.csproj` file ?

Comment: When I try to add it to my question, I'm a good 2k characters over the limit.  Is there a particular section you would like to look at or have another idea on how to share it?

Comment: Copy paste only the packages related to Application Insights or send an image which clearly shows the packages versions.

Comment: Added the parts of the .csproj that deal with the ApplicationInsights package to my question.